# PHP multi dimensional array extract and remove

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP 5.3

I am attempting to extract and remove the phrase `somestuffIdontwant` from my multi-dimensional array.

What is the best method for this?

Array structure:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
"   string(148) "20170624 somestuffIdontwant 123425 086
    ["L-S_State"]=>
"   string(103) "state somestuffIdontwant entry1
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
"   string(148) "20170624 somestuffIdontwant 123425 086
    ["L-S_State"]=>
"   string(103) "state somestuffIdontwant entry2
  }
}
```

`

Comment: please be clear in your question

Comment: I think it's clear and your down vote based on spelling is pompous. If you don't understand the question you should be clear on your concern. I want to remove "somestuffIdontwant" from each array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `str_replace` or `ereg_replace`

Something like this:

```
foreach ($array as &$record) {
  foreach ($record as &$index) {
    $index = str_replace('somestuffIdontwant', '', $index);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. As when I did echo gettype it returned "array" and I assumed that it would not allow for string comparisons.